# How to filter list of list and keep elements that are in other list

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var l = new List<List<string>>() { {"a","b","c"}, {"d","g","f"}}
and tokeep = new List<string>() { "a","c","d" }
```

I am trying to filter l and keep only elements that are in `tokeep`
I have

```
l = l.Where(s => s.Where(s => tokeep.Contains(s)).ToList()).ToList();
```

But it does not work.
I am trying to get `l = { {"a","c"}, {"d"} }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the result you want to have based on the given input. Also, consider providing a second example that shows which element should be kept and which element should be removed.

Comment: Sorry I've edited.

Comment: Please also add an example when there is no overlapping between one element in list `l` and the other list `tokeep`. How should the resulting list look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get l = { {"a","c"}, {"d"} }

Specifically it sounds like you want the *outer* list to be the same length, but for each element of that list (for each *inner* list) you want to filter the contents.

Rather than two nested `.Where()` operations, that's a `.Select()` operation with a nested `.Where()` operation.  For example:

```
var l = new List<List<string>>() { new() { "a", "b", "c" }, new() { "d", "g", "f" } };
var tokeep = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "d" };
l = l.Select(s => s.Where(x => tokeep.Contains(x)).ToList()).ToList();
```

The `.Select()` projects the list into a new list, returning the result of its lambda expression for each element in the list.  That lambda expression is simply calling `.Where()` on that element, filtering the items within that *inner* list.

In the event that any of the *inner* lists end up being empty, you can remove those as a separate operation:

```
var l = new List<List<string>>() { new() { "a", "b", "c" }, new() { "d", "g", "f" } , new() { "g", "h" } };
var tokeep = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "d" };
l = l.Select(s => s.Where(x => tokeep.Contains(x)).ToList())
     .Where(s => s.Any())
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a result list with the following two LINQ methods:

- [`Enumerable.Intersect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-intersect-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) - This methods takes two enumerables (lists are enumerables) and returns a new list with elements, which exists only in both source enumerables. So when you have one list `{"d","g","f"}` and another list `{ "a","c","d" }` you will get a new enumerable `{"d"}`, since the element `d` is the only element in both lists.
- [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))) - This method will convert each element of an enumerable (again, lists are enumerables) to a different value, maybe even to a different type.

We use these methods and start with the list `l`. For each element we will calculate the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection) of the next element in list `l` and the other list `tokeep`. We will return the result of this intersect calculation as a new list. That way the overall result is still a `List<List<string>>` (and not a `List<IEnumerable<string>>`). The source code can look like this:

```
List<List<string>> l = new List<List<string>>() 
{
     new List<string>{"a","b","c"},
     new List<string>{"d","g","f"}
};
List<string> tokeep = new List<string>() 
{
    "a",
    "c",
    "d" 
};

List<List<string>> result = l
    .Select(first =>
    {
        return first.Intersect(tokeep).ToList();
    })
    .ToList();

for (int i=0; i<result.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> list = result[i];
    string valuesAsString = string.Join(",", list);
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] {valuesAsString}");
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
[0] a,c
[1] d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using LINQ Intersect method to find the common elements between each inner list in `l` and `tokeep`.

```
var l = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" }, new List<string> { "d", "g", "f" } };
var tokeep = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "d" };

// Filter each inner list in l and keep only elements that are in tokeep
var filteredLists = l.Select(innerList => innerList.Intersect(tokeep).ToList()).ToList();

// Remove any empty inner lists
filteredLists.RemoveAll(innerList => innerList.Count == 0);

// Update l with the filtered lists
l = filteredLists;
```